# If $||f-g|| < ||f^{-1}||^{-1}$, then $f$ is isomorphism implies $g$ is also isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $E$, $F$ be Banach space, $f,g \in L(E,F)$ and $f$ is isomorphism. Prove that if $||f-g|| < ||f^{-1}||^{-1}$, then $g$ is isomorphism.

Hi everybody. I got stuck on this problem and can't find any clue to solve this. Can anybody help me? I really appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$
\|\text{id}_E-f^{-1}g\|=\|f^{-1}(f-g)\|\le \|f^{-1}\|\cdot\|f-g\|<1,
$$
therefore 
$$
h:=\text{id}_E-(\text{id}_E-f^{-1}g)=f^{-1}g
$$ 
is invertible and 
$$
h^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\text{id}_E-f^{-1}g)^n.
$$
Since $g=fh$,  it follows that $g$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\|1-f^{-1}g\| < 1
$$
Consider the expression
$$
h:= f\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-f^{-1}g)
$$
The series converges absolutely, and so converges in $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$. Check that $h$ is the inverse of $g$.